# Initializing class member (vector) in constructor via initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11

The C++11 standard gives an opportunity to initialize a vector with an initialization list like this.

```
vector <int> a {3, 5, 6, 2};
```

I am just wondering if it is possible to initialize a vector which is a member of class in a constructor via initialization list.

I looked for such a thing but I did not find it on the Internet or here on Stack Overflow, so I thought that I should ask for it.  I hope that not only I, but also others will find it useful.

**I do not want** to make vector a **static member** of a class.

The class should look like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        vector <int> myvector;
        //Here should be a constructor 
};
```

It could be used like this:

```
Foo aa{1, 2, 3, 6, 1}; // it should initialize a vector
```

Comment: `Foo::Foo(std::initializer_list<int> init_list) : a(init_list) {}`

Comment: For the record, this is not the "new" standard any more.. there have been 1.5 newer ones since ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yea you got right haha :)

Comment: That's an `std::initializer_list`, not an _initiali(s/z)er list_ or an "initialization list". I don't want to be pedantic for its own sake, but the Standard uses such similar terms for different things that we have no choice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ! You just need to take in an `std::initializer_list` and initialize your vector with it.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(std::initializer_list<int> l)
    : _vec{l} { }

    std::vector<int> _vec;
};
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a73a6bf61af3f5f)

Comment: Big thanks for your answer it is really bizzare that I didn't find it.

Comment: Yep especially as the answer is right there in the "Related" questions list!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a constructor for Foo that takes an initializer list, and pass it to the vector.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list for an example that does exactly what you need